# Swift - Place the correct direction of navigation arrows

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, arkit

I am implementing a navigation software with ARKit. I wanna display the path with arrows but i don't know how to set the correct direction of the arrows.

Now, all my arrows are in the same direction like this: [Picture_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkNqG.png)

Below is my code

```
func addArrow(position: SCNVector3) {
    let plane = SCNPlane()
    let theNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    geometryNode.position = position
    geometryNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2
    geometryNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contants = self.arrowImage
    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(geometryNode)
}
```

Now i hope to change the arrow direction like this: [Picture_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeaOn.png)

How can I do it? Is it possible to change the direction of arrow based on the position of the next node? Thanks.

Comment: were you able to find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

SceneKit's SCNLookAtConstraint may be useful

Comment: After using it, I found that the code "geometryNode.eulerAngles.x" is invalid. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: I imagine you get rid of that line - rotate the geometry instead of the node?